# Find next date in series by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data like this:

```
sample.data <- rbind(data.table(start.date=seq(from=as.Date("2010-01-01"), to=as.Date("2014-12-01"), by="quarter"),
                 Group=c("A","B","C","D"), rnorm(20, 5)),
                 data.table(start.date=seq(from=as.Date("2010-01-01"), to=as.Date("2014-12-01"), by="quarter"),
                 Group=c("A","B","C","D"), rnorm(20, 3))
                 )
```

I would like to create an `end.date` column that equals the next earliest `start.date` value for each group.

So, for example, the first `start.date` for `Group==A` is `2010-01-01`. The next earliest `start.date` for `Group==A` is `2011-01-01`. So the final result should look like this when sorted by `Group`:

```
                start.date Group   end.date
                2010-01-01     A 2011-01-01
                2010-01-01     A 2011-01-01
                2011-01-01     A 2012-01-01
                2011-01-01     A 2012-01-01
                2012-01-01     A 2013-01-01
                2012-01-01     A 2013-01-01
                2013-01-01     A 2014-01-01
                2013-01-01     A 2014-01-01
                2014-01-01     A         NA
                2014-01-01     A         NA
                2010-04-01     B 2011-04-01
                2010-04-01     B 2011-04-01
                2011-04-01     B 2012-04-01
                2011-04-01     B 2012-04-01
```

And so on. Ideally I would like to do this by reference, like

`sample.data[, end.date := EXPRESSION]`

but am at a loss for where to start. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so:

```
events = unique(sample.data[ , .(Group, start.date) ])
events[, next.date := shift(start.date, type="lead"), by=Group]

sample.data[events, on=c("Group", "start.date"), end.date := next.date ]
```

In my opinion, the OP should have a table like `events` anyways, in keeping with database design / [tidy data](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10). The result looks like

```
> sample.data[ order(Group, start.date) ]

    start.date Group   end.date
 1: 2010-01-01     A 2011-01-01
 2: 2010-01-01     A 2011-01-01
 3: 2011-01-01     A 2012-01-01
 4: 2011-01-01     A 2012-01-01
 5: 2012-01-01     A 2013-01-01
 6: 2012-01-01     A 2013-01-01
 7: 2013-01-01     A 2014-01-01
 8: 2013-01-01     A 2014-01-01
 9: 2014-01-01     A       <NA>
10: 2014-01-01     A       <NA>
11: 2010-04-01     B 2011-04-01
12: 2010-04-01     B 2011-04-01
...
```

Comment: For now I'm pointing to the Docs page just because the official vignette on joins isn't out yet.

Comment: This is great, thanks. And a whole new `data.table` functionality to learn. Is this a new addition to the package?

Comment: The `on` syntax is new since 1.9.6 I think, but the `X[Y, xvar := yvar ]` has been there as long as I've been using the package. It's one of its best features, for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

## Initial approach

One option would be to make use of the [**`dplyr`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) workflow:

```
require(dplyr); require(magrittr)
sample.data %<>%
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    mutate(end.date = sort(start.date, decreasing = FALSE)[2]) %>%
```

### Comments

You can manipulate `sort` function and `[n]` value to get *second smallest,* highest or any other date from within the group.

## Alternative approach

*Following the discussion in comments.*

```
sample.data %<>%
    arrange(Group, start.date) %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(end.date2 = sort(start.date, decreasing = FALSE)[row_number(Group) + 2]) %>% 
    arrange(Group)
```

### *Preview*

```
    >> head(sample.data, n = 4)
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: Group [1]

  start.date Group       V3  end.date2
      <date> <chr>    <dbl>     <date>
1 2010-01-01     A 4.899328 2011-01-01
2 2010-01-01     A 3.451904 2011-01-01
3 2011-01-01     A 5.779825 2012-01-01
4 2011-01-01     A 4.182594 2012-01-01
```

Comment: @Frank, thanks for your previous comment as well. I agree, I like *`dplyr`-based* workflow for its readability but there is a number of ways it could be done in **R**.

Comment: Your `dplyr` solution and @Frank 's `data.table` solution both set the `end.date` the same for every observation in each `Group` group. Please see my desired output in the question.

Comment: @moman822 So basically, for each observation in the Group *A* it should provide dates in a reverse order starting from second earliest date?

Comment: @Konrad the new `end.date` should be the next (forward in time) `start.date` in the `Group`. I've expanded my sample desired output in the question which should give a clearer idea.

Comment: Your 'Alternative approach' answers my question but the 'Initial approach does not.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Grouping by `Group`, for each element of `start.date` in the current group, find its position in `sort(unique(start.date))` and return the value at the next position:

```
sample.data[, end.date := {u <- sort(unique(start.date)); u[match(start.date, u) + 1]}, 
  by = Group]
```

**2)** Using `ave`, the same approach also works without any packages:

```
transform(sample.data, end.date = ave(start.date, Group, FUN = 
   function(x) { u <- unique(sort(x)); u[match(x, u) + 1] }))
```